# InfoPath Form Works Under Admin Account But Not Under Regular User

Tags: document-library, infopath, permissions, database-connection, connection

An InfoPath browser enabled form that has udcx connections from a connection library, code in C# and some rules, was created and tested on the SharePoint server and functions more or less as designed on the server using the SharePoint service account.  When testing the form using a regular user's account, the following is shown upon loading the form.

> A database that contains data required for this form to function
>   correctly cannot be found.
>
> An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server.  Log
>   ID:5566

The error is repeated five (5) times.  In Event Viewer, it shows that there is a DataAdapterException was thrown.  After that, the form loads, but a dropdown list that pulls its data from database via a udcx connection shows no options at all in the list.

Permissions settings is the most obvious place to start.  The InfoPath form is set to Fully Trusted.  The permissions of document library where the form resides has been checked over and over as well as the permissions of the connection library with the udcx files, but the form still gives the same error when accessed as a regular user, but no problems using the SharePoint admin account.  When permissions for both libraries were set to Full Control, for all regular users (bad idea, but just to see if it would work) the errors still persists.

Any help and advice in handling the situation are more than welcome.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Ensure the user has rights to access the database
- Also ensure the connection file has been approved - A sharepoint admin can access a non approved Ucdx file. Go to the connection library and approve the file.

Comment: Before getting to this state, I ensured that the udcx files had been approved.  I'll need to double check the database rights though.

Comment: User access rights to the database seemed to be the issue.  It's now seems to be functional for regular users as it is for the SharePoint admin account.  

Thank you very much for you help!!

Comment: I am encountering similar issue on my end. What Rights did you assign to which account in Database? also how did you do so, directly on sql database or in central admin.

Comment: The rights will need to be assigned to the SQL DB, it depends on your requirements, if read is what the users are after then just give read access if not both read/write.